# Creating custom namespace [classes,ID] for bootstrap using less prepreocessor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap has .table and .table-responsive for tables, I don't need a .table I want it applied to all table so I used it as mixin

`table { .table; }
table.responsive { .table.responsive; }`

but now I will have both of them in my css file, I just want to have my custom created classes and remove the bootstraps name spaced classes....

I have tried to implement is many ways but no luck...

what if bootstrap provide all of its classes as mixins and call them in a different file, allowing users to make their own namespaced stylesheet...

Comment: You could just edit your copy of Bootstrap to make `.table` a mixin instead of a class. You just have to simply change `.table {` to `.table() {`. Same for other classes.

Comment: hacking in to the core is a very, very bad idea.. When ever a new version of bootstrap comes u have to look for commits made and change the code again and again....yuks.. Besides this is not **only my problem**, people who want to have custom namespace in bootstrap are facing this from a ling time... Its time to put a solution for it in the core itself..